# Are there Amazon EC2 IAM Policy Actions for Tags?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I just had a look at the IAM user guide. Looks like the EC2 section is very short and not really detailed.

Are there any IAM Policy Actions for creating/deleting EC2 insance tags? Something like *ec2:CreateTags* or *ec2:DeleteTags*?

**Update:**

Ok, I made a test. It is the undocumented "ec2:CreateTags" and "ec2:DeleteTags" policy action.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the snippet of IAM policy that is working for me for creating tags.

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "ec2:CreateTags"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also dealing with IAM this days (documentation is horrible). As far as I know IAM won't deal with tags, you need regular EC2 tools to do that, but it does create groups, maybe you can do something with that?

Good luck with IAM, so far it looks quite buggy and horribly documented to me.

Comment: Yeah, it is not detailed for every service. I made a test and "ec2:CreateTags" and "ec2:DeleteTags" works.

Comment: Oh good to hear it works :)

Comment: But it is not officially. I will get in touch with the AWS.

Comment: see: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=58687&messageID=217466#217466